# Okta is returning an invalid redirect uri when connected to IdentityServer 3 and performing sign out

Tags: redirect, openid, logout, identityserver3, okta

I'm trying to integrate Okta as a third party Identity Provider for a system I am working on that is using the IdentityServer 3 framework to support my customers that use Okta. I have everything working great except log out. When a user logs out of my system, it initiates the end session call back to Okta to log the user out. My problem is that the Identity Server is sending a session id along with the post logout redirect uri for context, but Okta refuses to accept the redirect uri because it is not known. I've tried multiple variations in the setup in Okta for this url but because the id value is dynamic, i'm not able to specify an exact url. Is there a way to have it support any urls that are going to a specific hostname or even up to the page path? I've tried adding my host into the API security area for trusted origins but it did not work either. I've also tried overriding the postback url for my system to be a static page, but then the IdentityServer Signout message cookie is never cleaned up correctly. This same code works without any problems when running for Azure as the IDP. Has anyone run into this before and have any thoughts? Any help is appreciated.

An example of the post to Okta at signout with the postback url is something like this,

```
https://dev-xx.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fmyurl.com%2fidp%2flogout%2f%3fid%3d83617adbc6769e5d4d0fbca4dced3991&max_age=5&id_token_hint=eyJraWQiOiJ1aXJYc1RYTkTVVGenBXU1JfMWt6WndNSXBQQUVqT0dndWhjbloxR3pNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.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.gvG_8dnlAMr9XI-atCjIKVF04L4oMzerXmeT0BAG76RLle-q2pgb8PDvV4cTicLH16QLzboSgocC6t6WoegbUeJLLuzZHd2rQkm8Y4iRheoV05uKhd2mpLA9LyexlJ9oVJ8Xi_D4BqN_bygphAv79B4L8-Ezz3YgGDmSkK3WutB55_r_7XM0OCCCetvNu4S8KXbKHUxgg5cpQ6y7o-d5eIH6I8bpoOoA0gy7Liwsm7IyQUe5_jdorObgBHIEfDx4mjNRENJUQ7InASwbL7eND7COZYyXRwzn7vHU0_XkBaUW9wsY-VJUaihOwEcgVS1MPbGLoSUY9k0TmcUVN3-Q&state=83617adbc6769e5d4d0fbca4dced3991&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=1.0.40306.1554
```

the id=83617... is what is tripping up Okta from trusting the redirect url. I've tried adding all of these combinations of urls into the logout redirect uri setup and none let it accept it,

```
https://myurl.com/idp/logout/
https://myurl.com/idp/logout/?id=  
https://myurl.com/idp/logout?id=  
https://myurl.com  
https://myurl.com/  
https://myurl.com/idp  
https://myurl.com/idp/  
https://myurl.com/idp/logout
```

None seem to work.

Comment: Can you add a couple example URLs? I'm guessing it is something like:
`https://your-domain/logout?session=foobar` ?

Comment: Agreed, we need to see some examples (I'm not an IdentityServer expert, sorry). What part of the URL is dynamic?

Comment: Added an example to the original post.

Comment: Unknown or different redirect url is not trusted by the identity providers. You might want to rewrite your logout process, e.g. keep the id value in a cookie and read it from there after logout. In that case your logout url will not be different.